# Using JPA 2.0 @Cacheable in J2SE with Spring, EHCache and Hibernate, without Hibernate specific annotations

Tags: hibernate, spring, caching, jpa-2.0, ehcache

I am trying to get JPA 2.0 Caching working in my Spring 3.0.5 application which uses Hibernate and EhCache. I do not wish to have my application bound to Hibernate and EhCache and wish to have it make use of pure JPA code only as far as possible.

I managed to get caching working with EHCache and Hibernate by setting the Hibernate specific `@Cache` annotation on top of my entity classes and specifying `org.hibernate.cacheable` as a query hint for my named queries.

However, when I try to switch those to `@Cacheable(true)` and setting the query hint `javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode` to `"CacheRetrieveMode.USE"` (I also tried just `"USE"`) it doesn't work and my named query which should be cached is just getting retrieved again from the database. I am specifying these within the annotation of the NamedQuery itself using the `hints = ...`

I tried various combinations of `<shared-cache-mode>`, `ENABLE_SELECTIVE`, `DISABLE_SELECTIVE` etc. but none seems to have any effect.

I am starting to suspect that this functionality is not available on J2SE. Am I missing something? Should I enable some extra annotation handler from the Spring application context?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using? Because this was implemented in 3.5, see https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4660.

Comment: Does it work with Hibernate annotations? Is it just the JPA annos that are broken? If not, it could be the way you're designing your query.

Comment: Can you check if the underlying cache i.e. EHCache has any issues with supporting '@Cacheable(true)' and 'javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode'? I suspect there might be some issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, its not pure JPA, but I've used the EhCache annotation for Spring (http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/UsingCacheable) and it works great.  Annotate the DAO method you want to cache with `@Cacheable(cacheName="myCache")`, configure the cache in your Spring configuration, and watch the DB calls disappear.

Comment: Will '@Cacheable' work when data in DB is modified ? I mean how the cache data is invalidated ?

Comment: You need to annotate the method you want to use to refresh the cache, usually on your update and remove DAO methods.  See http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/UsingTriggersRemove.  There are 2 basic options: empty the cache (the simpler method), or atomicly remove cache items (more involved).

Comment: Thanks but its not what I am looking for. I am looking for a pure JPA solution. For a vendor specific solution I can simply stick to the EHCache and Hibernate vendor specific annotations, which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Query caching with Hibernate JPA impl it's not possible without hint **org.hibernate.cacheable** up to current version 4.1. Of course you may store it in xml descriptors in named query defenitions and change it for different JPA providers (or store define hints for all variants). But in our projects we implement additional utility that adds hints to named query by external config (props). Eg:

   ru.citc.jpa.queryhint.[query_name]=org.hibernate.cacheable\=true, javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode\=USE,etc...
2. Entity cahcing may be configured by external properties. See [there](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html-single/Hibernate_Entity_Manager_Reference_Guide/index.html#setup-configuration-bootstrapping) . Example:

   ```
       <prop key="hibernate.ejb.classcache.ru.citc.migcredit.csrfront.model.Form">read-write,ScriptExecution</prop>
   <prop key="hibernate.ejb.collectioncache.ru.citc.migcredit.csrfront.model.Form.fields">read-write,ScriptExecution</prop>
   <prop key="hibernate.ejb.collectioncache.ru.citc.migcredit.csrfront.model.Form.constraints">read-only,ScriptDesignCollections</prop>
   ```

As result we have pure JPA code with external config for caching and other provider specific features. That work perfectly for Hibernate and EclipseLink. As additional bonus we have different caching strategies for different application modules (eg. admin web app do not cache metadata tables, but operator web app cache it read only).

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be working for me, with Hibernate ORM/EhCache 4.2.6.Final and Spring Framework 3.2.4.RELEASE:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="example.stackoverflow"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode">ENABLE_SELECTIVE</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I've annotated my Entity class with `@javax.persistence.Cacheable` and I only see Hibernate logging SQL queries when getting something that's not in the cache. The key seems to be using the JPA property to specify whether to enable the cache rather than the hibernate-specific property.